# How to use regex in php for phrase containing meta-characters?

Tags: php, regex

Anyone know how to use a php regex to remove text from a string that contains regex meta-characters?

For example -

Text-string before -

```
"Look at the shiny apple [word]" //where 'word' could be anything
```

Text-string after -

```
"look at the shiny apple"
```

Comment: Are you looking to replace a specific string which happens to contain metacharacters (this was answered already) or generally any string which contains metacharacters? Then you have to enumerate, like `[][^$.\*+?()]` (this is a possibly incomplete character class, just to give you the idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replace something with regex using [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

If you want to match a special character literally you have to escape the character in the regular expression using a backslash like this `\[` (if you want to match a "[").

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/Look at the shiny apple \[\w+\]/gi','Look at the shiny apple', $subject);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: 1Clean and straight-forward, ga

Comment: This would replace the whole sentence and not only the word in square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would look something like this:

```
"(?<=Look at the shiny apple )\S*"
```

The (?<=) is a positive lookbehind, it says it must exist before the match, but not to include it in the match.

This is a good tool for testing and figuring out regex: http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Edit: as noted below, without a space after the .* it would match the rest of the data, \S could also be used. Thanks Jesse

Comment: well, if they wanted to capture every character after "Look at the shiny apple", that would work, but I'd imagine this would at least be `(?<=Look at the shiny apple\s*)\S*`, so it won't capture the entire rest of the string contents.

Comment: I had actually forgotten to mention, there's a space after the .*, but it's not quite visible here. Sorry about that, yes \S would work as well.

Comment: edited the original post to better clarify, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: you'll need a `*` there too, or it'll only match the first character ;)